# Generate binaries using macros inside a source file

Tags: c++, g++, window

I am trying to generate output file by the use of macro in source file.
Whatever a macro name is, generate the final .exe file by using the macro name.

```
#include <iostream>

#define Apple
//#define Banana
//#define Mango

int main()
{
...
}
```

How could i generate an output file name like Apple.exe ?

compiler: g++
OS: windows

Comment: You cannot. The output name is determined by the linker invocation. What do you need this for?

Comment: I have several GUIs inside a main.cpp file that will be built using a macro name. I want to have a separate builds and in turn separate .exe for every macro.

Comment: Isn't that just a matter of setting the macro name when you build the corresponding thing? eg `g++ -o Banana main.cpp -DNAME=Banana` `g++ -o Apple main.cpp -DNAME=Apple`

Comment: hmm, i think thats right

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot steer the name of the final linker artifacts (executable in your case) from within the source code.
This needs to be done using the `-o <filename>` linker flag, thus in your case

```
> g++ -o Banana.exe main.cpp -DNAME=Banana
```

To control this more easily you can define these as variables in a makefile, e.g. like

```
# Comment the current, and uncomment a different definiton to change the executables
# name and the macro definition for NAME
FINAL_NAME = Banana
# FINAL_NAME = Apple
# FINAL_NAME = Mango

$(FINAL_NAME).exe : main.cpp
        g++ -o $(FINAL_NAME).exe main.cpp -DNAME=$(FINAL_NAME)
```